# Change just the direction of gradient on hover

Tags: css, hover, linear-gradients

I have a button with a gradient, and I'd like for the gradient to switch directions on hover. Here is the starting CSS:

```
.button-1 {
    border: 1px solid #15440a;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #2890b;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#299c0f 20%, #1a7b09 80%);
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
.button-1:hover {
    /* change just direction of gradient */
    /* keep colors the same */
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just switch places of colors inside `linear-gradient` property.

```
   .button-1:hover {
        background-image: linear-gradient(#1a7b09 20%, #299c0f 80%);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EkYE5/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve changing the gradient direction only by keeping your gradient code the same, and adding 'to top,' ahead of the gradient colors:

```
.button-1:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #299c0f 20%, #1a7b09 80%);
{
```